# Strive to ultimate bash argument parsing

Tags: bash

I've tried my best to write argument parser to cover all my needs and I won't need to edit the body of parsing loop, never again(:)) to add/remove parsable flags. The resulting code seem to cover's my needs but there are things I don't like about it.

What it does:

It can parse any quantity of positional args, short flags(-f) and long flags(--flags/--flags=) provided at any order, no need to edit parsing loop. All values after flags (short n long) will set the corresponding var value (flagged_args_var_names), variable can have any name, only position matters.
e.g.

`-u admin --host localhost --default_database=users`

```bsh
echo $user #yields 'admin'
echo $host #yields 'localhost'
echo $default_db #yields 'users'
```

`first_arg another_arg last_arg`

```bsh
posarg[0]=first_arg
posarg[1]=another_arg
posarg[2]=last_arg
```

Here it is:

```bsh
# set flags and names of vars to be set [move to worker scipt]
flags_short=() # e.g. -u -h -d
flags_long=() # e.g. --user --host --database
flagged_args_var_names=() # e.g. user/user_name, host, database
posargs=()

function name_of_arg() {
  haystack="${@:1:$#-1}";needle="${@: -1}"; i=0
  for cur_hs in ${haystack[@]}; do
    if [[ "${cur_hs}" == "${needle}" ]]; then echo ${flagged_args_var_names[${i}]} && exit 0; fi
    i=$((i+1));
  done
  echo '' && exit 1;
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  cur_arg=$1; unset farg_name
  if [[ $cur_arg == -* ]]; then # flag
    if [[ $cur_arg == --*=* ]];then #--flag=arg_val
      cur_val="$(echo $cur_arg|tr "=" "\n"|tail -n 1)"
      cur_arg="$(echo $cur_arg|tr "=" "\n"|head -n 1)"
    else                            #-f arg_val or --flag arg_val 
      cur_val=$2
    fi
    if [[ $(name_of_arg ${flags_short[@]} "$cur_arg") ]]; then #arg name for -f arg_val
      farg_name=$(name_of_arg ${flags_short[@]} "$cur_arg")
    elif [[ $(name_of_arg ${flags_long[@]} "$cur_arg") ]]; then #arg name for --flag arg_val/--flag=arg_val
      farg_name=$(name_of_arg ${flags_long[@]} "$cur_arg")
    fi
    if [[ ! -z ${farg_name+x} ]]; then #found arg_name for flag
      declare $farg_name="${cur_val}"; 
      if [[ $cur_val == $2 ]]; then shift; fi
    else # unknown flag
      echo "Illegal option $cur_arg"; exit 1
    fi
  else                         # positional arg
    posargs+=("$1")
  fi
shift || true
done || true
done
```

check:

```bsh
# echo "user: $user"
# echo "host: $host"
# echo "database: $database"

# echo "Pos args: ${posargs[@]}"
```

usage examples
(assuming script resides in collect_args.sh file in project folder):

1. Backup specified vms to folder

```bsh
flags_short=(-u -p -h -d) # set flags and names of vars to be set
flags_long=(--user --password --host --destination)
flagged_args_var_names=(user password esx_host destination_path)
posargs=()

. collect_args.sh #that's my arg parser
vm_names=("${posargs[@]}")


for vm_name in ${vm_names[@]}
do
 #bad idea, I know
 ovftool --powerOffSource vi://${user}:${password}@${esx_host}/${vm_name} ${destination_path}/${vm_name}/${vm_name}.ovf"
done
```

result

```bsh
./export_vms_new.sh --user itsme --password blebla456 -d path -h my.esx.srv vm_1 vm_2 vm_win3
ovftool --powerOffSource vi://itsme:blebla456@my.esx.srv/vm_1 path/vm_1/vm_1.ovf
ovftool --powerOffSource vi://itsme:blebla456@my.esx.srv/vm_2 path/vm_2/vm_2.ovf
ovftool --powerOffSource vi://itsme:blebla456@my.esx.srv/vm_win3 path/vm_win3/vm_win3.ovf
```

2. Establish ssh tunnels

```bsh
flags_short=(-u -h -p -f -s) # set flags and names of vars to be set
flags_long=(--user --host --port --flags --shift)
flagged_args_var_names=(user host remote_port extra_flags port_shift)
posargs=()

. collect_args.sh
remote_hosts=("${posargs[@]}")


# for remote_host in ${remote_hosts[@]}
for i in "${!remote_hosts[@]}"
do
  ssh ${extra_flags} $((i+port_shift))043:${host}:${remote_port} ${user}@${remote_hosts[$i]} -N
done
```

result

```bsh
./ssh_forward_ports.sh -u me -h localhost --port=443 --flags '-l -F' --shift=6 instance1.gcp instance2.gcp instance3.gcp
ssh -l -F 6043:localhost:443 me@instance1.gcp -N
ssh -l -F 7043:localhost:443 me@instance2.gcp -N
ssh -l -F 8043:localhost:443 me@instance3.gcp -N
```

Cons:

1. It's over bloated, hard to read, hard to modify.
2. It doesn't process boolean flags without arg value, e.g. if I'd like to make --powerOffSource from 1st example optional. I need not only to add array, but add different logic to already bloated script. Also the reason to modify arg processing loop.
3. Name yours

Problems:

1. I couldn't use select case, because of mixed up and alternating
   actions for various types of flags, this decreases script
   readability drastically.
2. I was unable to iterate array keys inside name_of_arg function, thus
   manual counter inc
3. I couldn't write proper "ternary operator" for the part were script
   getting arg name for -f and --flag arg_vals and I can't move it to
   function, because I can't pass array in nested function call.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time right now for a full review, but I spotted this minor oversight:

> ```
>       echo "Illegal option $cur_arg"; exit 1
> ```

I think that ought to be `echo >&2`.  We should always use the standard error stream for error messages, rather than the standard output stream.

Comment: Hi, tanks for the tip!